# How to show Bottom tab navigation in specific screens only

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have react native app which I am using react navigation and my navigation stack looks like the following:

```
<AppStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.primary2,
        elevation: 0, 
        shadowOpacity: 0,
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',

    }}>
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
      />
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="qr"
        component={qr}
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }} />
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AppStack.Screen
        name="Support"
        component={ChatScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />

</AppStack.Navigator>
```

I want to create `createBottomTabNavigator` but to be displayed in all screen in the AppStack except  the following home screen

```
<AppStack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false
            }}
    />
```

May I know what the best practice to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabBarVisible(boolean)` prop for this purpose.

```
<AppStack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: false
            }}
            navigationOptions:()=>{
               return {
                 tabBarVisible:false,
              }
            }
    />
```